# De un list C# a: Json en jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

Intento convertir un list en c# ASP.NET a un Json a través de un Webmethod.

Tengo una gráfica pastel que gracias a un slide track bar podría ser modificado el contenido. Para ello necesito enviar éstos datos a través de un webmethod.

Todo empieza cuando el usuario desliza el track bar hacia un mes distinto:

```
$("#ex19").slider();
$("#ex19").on("change", function (e) {        

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "erTendencia.aspx/Pie4_WM",
        data: '{name: "' + e.newValue + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: pie4_success,
        failure: function (response_pie4) {
            //$('#canales').removeClass("modalX");
            alert(response_pie4.d);
        }
    });

});
```

Código del Webmethod c#:

```
    public static string Pie4_WM(string name)
    {

        int month = Convert.ToInt16(name);
        List<string> ListPie4 = new List<string>();
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R1'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R2'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R3'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D3[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D3[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R4'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D4[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D4[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R5'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D5[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D5[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R6'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D6[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D6[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R7'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D7[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D7[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R8'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D8[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D8[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R9'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D9[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D9[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R10'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D10[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D10[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'R11'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D11[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D11[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");
        ListPie4.Add("{ruta: 'RUTA STANDBY'" + ", a3:" + ClassInteres.InteresClase.D12[month] + ", Cant:" + (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D12[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4) + "}");


        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(ListPie4);            
        return json;
    }
```

Éste webmethod me lanza la siguiente cadena de caracteres tipo json:

```
["{ruta: \u0027R1\u0027, a3:13714.190, Cant:0.2223366260227845679702863554}","{ruta: \u0027R2\u0027, a3:9168.930, Cant:0.1486481491388911856113848264}","{ruta: \u0027R3\u0027, a3:6555.930, Cant:0.1062857782079403911345430846}","{ruta: \u0027R4\u0027, a3:7147.190, Cant:0.1158713792169851545261915531}","{ruta: \u0027R5\u0027, a3:4217.480, Cant:0.0683744554741164778760775006}","{ruta: \u0027R6\u0027, a3:10675.170, Cant:0.1730675512020505138443730029}","{ruta: \u0027R7\u0027, a3:4151.140, Cant:0.0672989408596659322558732598}","{ruta: \u0027R8\u0027, a3:9554.590, Cant:0.1549005302997141796404467422}","{ruta: \u0027R9\u0027, a3:651.990, Cant:0.0105701654126561838847899147}","{ruta: \u0027R10\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0}","{ruta: \u0027R11\u0027, a3:4338.300, Cant:0.0703332084997106129655118746}","{ruta: \u0027RUTA STANDBY\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0}"]
```

Donde el \u0027 = son comillas simples '' ya que el serializer C# las ha modificado, según leí no tiene ningún efecto secundario ya que lo leería como comillas simples, pero cuando intento ponerlas como una variable independiente y directa, o sea así:

```
var test = [{ruta: \u0027R1\u0027, a3:13714.190, Cant:0.2223366260227845679702863554},{ruta: \u0027R2\u0027, a3:9168.930, Cant:0.1486481491388911856113848264},{ruta: \u0027R3\u0027, a3:6555.930, Cant:0.1062857782079403911345430846},{ruta: \u0027R4\u0027, a3:7147.190, Cant:0.1158713792169851545261915531},{ruta: \u0027R5\u0027, a3:4217.480, Cant:0.0683744554741164778760775006},{ruta: \u0027R6\u0027, a3:10675.170, Cant:0.1730675512020505138443730029},{ruta: \u0027R7\u0027, a3:4151.140, Cant:0.0672989408596659322558732598},{ruta: \u0027R8\u0027, a3:9554.590, Cant:0.1549005302997141796404467422},{ruta: \u0027R9\u0027, a3:651.990, Cant:0.0105701654126561838847899147},{ruta: \u0027R10\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0},{ruta: \u0027R11\u0027, a3:4338.300, Cant:0.0703332084997106129655118746},{ruta: \u0027RUTA STANDBY\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0}];
```

El jquery me señala errores de redacción.

En fín, mi meta final es que el formato json sea el correcto, de ésta manera:

```
 var Str =   [{ruta: 'R1', a3:13714.190, Cant:0.2223366260227845679702863554},{ruta: 'R2', a3:9168.930, Cant:0.1486481491388911856113848264},{ruta: 'R3', a3:6555.930, Cant:0.1062857782079403911345430846},{ruta: 'R4', a3:7147.190, Cant:0.1158713792169851545261915531},{ruta: 'R5', a3:4217.480, Cant:0.0683744554741164778760775006},{ruta: 'R6', a3:10675.170, Cant:0.1730675512020505138443730029},{ruta: 'R7', a3:4151.140, Cant:0.0672989408596659322558732598},{ruta: 'R8', a3:9554.590, Cant:0.1549005302997141796404467422},{ruta: 'R9', a3:651.990, Cant:0.0105701654126561838847899147},{ruta: 'R10', a3:0, Cant:0},{ruta: 'R11', a3:4338.300, Cant:0.0703332084997106129655118746},{ruta: 'RUTA STANDBY', a3:0, Cant:0}];
```

Una vez logrado esto la gráfica se actualiza con el siguiente jquery code

```
function pie4_success(response_pie4)
{
var myStr = response_pie4.d;



var char4_B_ = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: {
        type: "array",
        data: myStr
    },
    map: function (dataItem) {
        var tag = [];
        tag.push(dataItem.ruta);
        tag.push(dataItem['a3']);
        tag.push(dataItem['Cant']);
        return $.extend(dataItem, { tag: tag });
    }
  });
```

Según el developer tool de chrome, la variable myStr, está recibiendo la sig. información:

```
 "["{ruta: \u0027R1\u0027, a3:13714.190, Cant:0.2223366260227845679702863554}","{ruta: \u0027R2\u0027, a3:9168.930, Cant:0.1486481491388911856113848264}","{ruta: \u0027R3\u0027, a3:6555.930, Cant:0.1062857782079403911345430846}","{ruta: \u0027R4\u0027, a3:7147.190, Cant:0.1158713792169851545261915531}","{ruta: \u0027R5\u0027, a3:4217.480, Cant:0.0683744554741164778760775006}","{ruta: \u0027R6\u0027, a3:10675.170, Cant:0.1730675512020505138443730029}","{ruta: \u0027R7\u0027, a3:4151.140, Cant:0.0672989408596659322558732598}","{ruta: \u0027R8\u0027, a3:9554.590, Cant:0.1549005302997141796404467422}","{ruta: \u0027R9\u0027, a3:651.990, Cant:0.0105701654126561838847899147}","{ruta: \u0027R10\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0}","{ruta: \u0027R11\u0027, a3:4338.300, Cant:0.0703332084997106129655118746}","{ruta: \u0027RUTA STANDBY\u0027, a3:0, Cant:0}"]"
```

Agrego una imagen de la gráfica. Saludos.

[image: RUTA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tiene que generar una lista de string para el json, deberias crear una clase

```
public class CharItem
{
    public string ruta { get; set; }
    public double a3 { get; set; }
    public double Cant { get; set; }
}

public static string Pie4_WM(string name)
{

    int month = Convert.ToInt16(name);
    List<CharItem> ListPie4 = new List<CharItem>();

    ListPie4.Add(new CharItem() {ruta= "R1", a3 = ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month], Cant = (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4)});
    ListPie4.Add(new CharItem() {ruta= "R2", a3 = ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month], Cant = Convert.ToDouble(ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4)});

    //demas items

    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(ListPie4);            
    return json;
}
```

cada item de la lista es una clase que se serializara a json

Utilice

http://json2csharp.com/

para obtener la clase en base al json que defines

---

Tambien podrias probar no realizar ninguna serializacion

[Return JSON data (object) from WebMethod (PageMethod) in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-JSON-data-object-from-WebMethod-PageMethod-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

sino devolver la lista directamente

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<CharItem> Pie4_WM(string name)
{

    int month = Convert.ToInt16(name);
    List<CharItem> ListPie4 = new List<CharItem>();

    ListPie4.Add(new CharItem() {ruta= "R1", a3 = ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month], Cant = (ClassInteres.InteresClase.D1[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4)});
    ListPie4.Add(new CharItem() {ruta= "R2", a3 = ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month], Cant = Convert.ToDouble(ClassInteres.InteresClase.D2[month] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie4)});

    //demas items


    return ListPie4;
}
```

como desde el $.ajax defines el contentType como json lo devolvera serializado en ese formato

Comment: Genial! Gracias! Trabajó muy bien! Intenté con no serializar y agregar la clase igual.